# Android unregister SensorManager doesn't work after changing screen orientation

Tags: android, sensormanager

I'm writing app with SensorManager and I have problem with unregistering SensorManager after changing screen orientation, I mean it doesn't work.

I'm creating it in this way:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (null == mSensorManager) {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometr = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometr, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
}
```

and that's how I unregister it:

```
mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mAccelerometr);
mSensorManager = null;
```

It works fine when screen orientation doesn't change, sensorManager is successfully unregistrated and onSensorChanged method isn't performed anymore. But if I change orientation than although I unregister sensorManager, onSensorChanged is still active. Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should be registering and unregistering in onResume and onPause instead:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (null == mSensorManager) {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometr = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometr, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (null != mSensorManager) {
       mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mAccelerometr);
       mSensorManager = null;
    }
}
```

See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

Comment: I've tried before registrating sensor in OnResume() but result was the same. I don't want to unregister it in onPause(), because I want this sensor to work also in background or when phone is blocked.

Comment: If you want the sensor to work in the background or when your App is not active, you need to create a service instead: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html